# Vagrant reporting VirtualBox guest additions out of date

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

Fairly new to Vagrant, so bear with me if I don't understand the process.

I downloaded a CentOS box off http://www.vagrantbox.es/

Started it up running VirtualBox 4.2.4 and got this message:

> [default] The guest additions on this VM do not match the install version of
>   VirtualBox! This may cause things such as forwarded ports, shared
>   folders, and more to not work properly. If any of those things fail on
>   this machine, please update the guest additions and repackage the
>   box.
>
> Guest Additions Version: 4.0.8
>
> VirtualBox Version: 4.2.4

So I used the [vbguest plugin](https://github.com/dotless-de/vagrant-vbguest) to update the guest additions, then repackaged the box as suggested. Having replaced the old box and loading it up I get the same message about guest additions being outdated, but vbguest reports that they are up to date (the automatic vbguest update is disabled in my Vagrantfile):

```
Vagrant::Config.run do |config|    
    config.vm.box = "centos56_64"

    config.vbguest.auto_update = false
    config.vbguest.no_remote = true
end
```

And the commands:

```
dtest$ vagrant up
[default] Importing base box 'centos56_64'...
[default] The guest additions on this VM do not match the install version of
VirtualBox! This may cause things such as forwarded ports, shared
folders, and more to not work properly. If any of those things fail on
this machine, please update the guest additions and repackage the
box.

Guest Additions Version: 4.0.8
VirtualBox Version: 4.2.4
[default] Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
[default] Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
[default] Forwarding ports...
[default] -- 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
[default] Creating shared folders metadata...
[default] Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
[default] Booting VM...
[default] Waiting for VM to boot. This can take a few minutes.
[default] VM booted and ready for use!
[default] Mounting shared folders...
[default] -- v-root: /vagrant

dtest$ vagrant vbguest --no-install
[default] Detected Virtualbox Guest Additions 4.2.4 --- OK.
[default] Virtualbox Guest Additions on host: 4.2.4 - guest's version is 4.2.4
```

Since they appear to be updated after an install, I could ignore the message. But is it possible to get rid of it?

Comment: ah, I found a vagrant issue on this: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/1179

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you've updated both Vagrant AND VirtualBox installs.  I had a similar issue (and came across this answer) and updating my VirtualBox install fixed it.

The problem was caused by having a box installed with newer guest additions than the installed VirtualBox software version.  In my case:

`GuestAdditions versions on your host (4.3.12) and guest (4.3.14) do not match.`

Adding this answer in case anyone else comes across the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing `vbguest` plugin which should take care of your Guest Additions:

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest
vagrant vbguest
vagrant up
```

If won't help, you need to download [VirtualBox Guest Additions](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) kernel modules inside the VM, e.g.

1. Download the ISO file, e.g.

   ```
   wget http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.0.20/VBoxGuestAdditions_5.0.20.iso -P /tmp
   ```
2. Mount the ISO file:

   ```
   sudo mount -o loop /tmp/VBoxGuestAdditions_5.0.20.iso /mnt
   ```
3. Run installer (add `-x` after `sh` to debug):

   ```
   sudo sh /mnt/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
   ```

If you're using Vagrant, installation is much simpler, just run: `vagrant vbguest`.

To find the right version of ISO file, check it at: http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/

Alternatively download ISO file to your host machien and replace the existing file (location may depend on your operating system, on macOS it's in */Applications/VirtualBox/Contents/MacOS*).